# Crop div to sibling div

Tags: html, css

I have the following overlapping divs:

```css
#circle {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#rect {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='circle'></div>
  <div id='rect'></div>
</div>
```

I want to make the circle div only appear inside of the rectangle div, but I **cannot** put one inside the other and use overflow. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't very practical, but the only way to do this without changing the markup is to crop it with the parent wrapper using `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden` on the parent. Adjust the location of the circle with `top: 30px` and `left: -20px`.

The parent would also need to set the rounded corners with 
`border-radius: 5px`.

Of course if this is just a background, then it should be set with a background radial gradient on the rectangle.

**Example**

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: -20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#rect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="circle"></div>
  <div id="rect"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's only about visual, use the circle as background of the div:

```css
#rect {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle 75px at 55px 105px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 99%,transparent);
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='rect'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is shorter and liked more. In how many seconds did you write it? :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT seconds is probably too much. It was a fraction of second :p

Comment: In my case, it's not just about the visual, I needed both the rectangle and circle elements separate